# What is the real meaning of resolution in computer vision?

Tags: laptop, display, resolution

I happened to watch a review and unboxing video for the **Dell E7470** laptop and then the reviewer clicked on **Settings** and then **Display** and checked the resolution of the laptop's screen. Windows reported **2560x1440** which is quite big for a laptop screen of that size, the resolution of that laptop's screen size should traditionally be **1366x768**, **Unless**, **Screen Dimension** is not
**Screen Resolution**,I know the monitor height and width translate or make up what is known as the **"Screen Resolution"**. Unless am wrong.

Comment: Get the i7 laptop

Comment: Okay I will , but what about the integrated graphics, will I lose a lot in terms of choosing hd 4600 over uhd 620?

Comment: Now I am confused. I thought the i7 had an UHD620 and the i5-7200U had a HD4600....? Look at       https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-UHD-Graphics-620-Mobile-Kaby-Lake-R-vs-Intel-HD-4600-Desktop-125-GHz/m320744vs2168   and          https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-4610M-vs-Intel-Core-i5-7200U/m11649vsm153577

Comment: No it is the reverse, the i5 7200u has a uhd 620 and the i7 has 4600 graphics

Answer (score 2):

Nope the resolution is the amount of pixels. Screen dimensions are the width and height. You can have a screen that is the same size, on which the pixels are smaller, which therefore has the same dimensions but a better resolution, and vice versa.

Compare [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0852W2WHV) two ~[24 inch monitors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014UL1Y7C). One has a much higher resolution (and price!)

Comment: why would they consider a **1366*768** laptopto be **720p**?

Comment: 720p = 1280 x 720, see https://www.quora.com/Why-is-1366x768-called-720p-not-768p for more info

Comment: also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/720p

Comment: so it is possible for a 1366 by 768 monitor to be 2560 by 1440 in the resolution though the difference will be the color coverage with the later being close to the resolution of a touch screen android phone? clarity?

Comment: 1366x768 and 2560x1440 are resolutions. The amount of pixels horizontally and vertically. My (android) phone has a 1520x720 screen. A 1366x768 monitor is called a 1366x768 monitor because that is its maximum resolution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

Comment: So there is a small screen laptop with 2560 by 1440 resolution?

Comment: This laptop has a screen that is 14 inch and it has a resolution of 2560x1440 https://www.amazon.com/ThinkPad-T490s-2560x1440-i7-8565U-Fingerprint/dp/B0924VZ93N/  and this laptop has a 17 inch screen (much bigger) but it has the same resolution, 2560x1440 pixels https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Alienware-2560x1440-Anti-Glare-AW17R4-7001SLV-PUS/dp/B073WR2SMQ/

Comment: Understood now.

Comment: This quality is a native property of the monitor or it is a quality of the monitor so can someone replace a 1366 by 768 resolution monitor with a 2560 by 1440 monitor for the same laptop model?

Comment: @KinyuaTimothyNjiru Theoretically, it would likely be possible to physically switch one laptop screen with a lower resolution (e.g. 1366x768) for one with a higher resolution (e.g. 2560x1440), similar to how different resolution monitors can be connected to the same PC. However, from a practical standpoint, it is probably unlikely you could do this in many cases. Laptops are often very specialized. That is, a screen for Laptop A and a screen for Laptop B might not be interchangeable, even if they are the same resolution, because of hardware connection differences.

Comment: @KinyuaTimothyNjiru Having two different screens from the same laptop model would likely improve the chances of screens being interchangeable, but I would still be cautious about the overall likelihood it could be done (again, from a hardware standpoint). Screen replacement is certainly a thing in laptop repair, though.

Comment: It's just that I really want a laptop model with a higher resolution that 1366*786, the quality of a modern smartphones displays

Comment: all these sellers are proposing a screen with 1366 by 786 quality resolution and I want better picture quality